# vscode react Hook is not automatically completed

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

Like the gif below, the useState is automatically completed, so it is convenient to import automatically, but sometimes it is not automatically completed.
At times like this, I often turn off and off the VScode, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should install ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets from extensions.

Comment: I installed it. The problem is that it works fine, but sometimes it doesn't.